# NodeJS processing for API calls sequentially, but resulting in stack overflow

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, stack

OK, so I have a situation where I cannot just fire thousands of requests to an API server.
I have a Node process (no UI) that I need to have process each API response/update sequentially, waiting for completion before sending the next request.
I may be making this more complicated than I think - not sure.  I can only figure out how to do this with recursive calls, but this results in a stack overflow as there can be thousands of records. The general process is this:

1. get rows from SQL table with ID's (result)
2. formulate and send of an API call to retrieve ID's info
3. if returned data has image data, write it back to SQL table
4. wait on this process so not to bombard API server with thousands of requests all at once
5. repeat until last ID is processed (can be thousands, more than stack space)

Here's sample code (not actual so ignore syntax errors if any)...
*UPDATED: actual running code with sensitive items removed*

```
var g_con = null;    //...yeah I know, globals are bad

//
//  [ found updating ]
//
function getSetImage(result, row, found) {

  if(row >= result.length) { //...exit on no row or last row processed
    con.end();
    return;
  }

  item = result[row];  //...next SQL row

  if((item !== undefined) && (item.autoid !== undefined)) {

    //...assemble API and send request
    //
    let url =   'https://...API header...'
              + item.autoid
              + '...API params...';

    request(url, (error, response, body) => {

      if(response.statusCode !== 200)
        throw('Server is not responding\n' + response.statusMessage);

      let imageData = JSON.parse(body);
      if((imageData.value[0]        !== undefined) &&
         (imageData.value[0].DETAIL !== undefined) &&
         (imageData.value[0].DETAIL.Value.length)   ) {

        //...post back to SQL
        //
        found++;
        console.log('\n' + item.autoid + '/['+ item.descr + '], ' + 'Found:' + found);

        qry = 'update inventory set image = "'+imageData.value[0].DETAIL.Value+'" where autoid = "'+item.autoid+'";';
        g_con.query(qry, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log('ERROR:',err.message, '\nSQL:['+err.sql+']\n');
            throw err.message;
          }
        });

        row++;
        setTimeout(()=>{getSetImage(result, row, found)}, 0);   //...nested call after SQL

      } else {

        row++;
        process.stdout.write('.');                                   //...show '.' for record, but no image
        setTimeout(()=>{getSetImage(result, row, found)}, 0);   //...nested call after SQL

      }

    }); //...request callback

  }

  // } else {

  //   throw '\nERROR! result['+row+'] undefined? Images found: '+found;
  // }
}


//
//  [ main lines ]
//
(() => {

  let params = null;
  try {

    params = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./config.json'));

    //...load autoids array from SQL inventory table - saving autoids
    //   autoids in INVENTRY join on par_aid's in INVENTRYIMAGES
    //
    g_con = mysql.createConnection(params.SQLConnection);
    g_con.connect((err) => {  if(err) {
                                console.log('ERROR:',err.message);
                                throw err.message;
                              }
                           });

    //...do requested query and return data or an error
    //
    let qry = 'select autoid, descr from inventory order by autoid;';
    g_con.query(qry, (err, results, flds) => {

        if (err || flds === undefined) {
          console.log('ERROR:',err.message, '\nSQL:['+err.sql+']\n');
          throw err.message;
        }

        console.log('Results length:',results.length);
        let row   = 0;
        let found = 0;
        getSetImage(results, row, found);

      });

  }

  catch (err) {
    console.log('Error parsing config parameters!');
    console.log(err);
  }

})();
```

So here's the answer using Promises (except for MySQL):

```
//
//  [ found updating ]
//
async function getSetImage(data) {

  for(let item of data) {

    if(item && item.autoid) {

      //...assemble API and send request
      //
      let url   = g_URLHeader + g_URLPartA + item.autoid + g_URLPartB;

      let image = await got(url).json().catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    err.message = 'API server is not responding';
                    throw err;
                  });

      if(image && image.value[0] && image.value[0].DETAIL &&
         image.value[0].DETAIL.Value.length       ) {
           console.log('\nFound: ['+item.autoid+' - '+item.descr
                       + '] a total of ' + g_found + ' in ' + g_count + ' rows');

          g_found++;

          //...post back to SQL
          //
          let qry = 'update inventory set image = "'
                  + image.value[0].DETAIL.Value
                  + '" where autoid = "'
                  + item.autoid+'";';
          await g_con.query(qry, (err) => {
                      if (err) {
                        console.log('ERROR:',err.message, '\nSQL:['+err.sql+']\n');
                        throw err.message;
                      }
                });

      } else {

          process.stdout.write('.');  //...show '.' for record, but no image

      }  //...if/else image.value

      g_count++;

    }  //...if item

  } //...for()

}
```

Comment: Well, this does not result in a stack overflow if you're calling the function recursively from within an asynchronous callback (which it appears you are).  When an asynchronous callback is called, the stack is empty and has completely unwound.  FYI, this would be a ton cleaner if you use a promise interface on everything (request library and database) and then use `async/await`.  You could literally just use a `for` loop with `await` and everything would nicely serialize inside one traditional look `for` loop.

Comment: FYI, your `con.query()` doesn't appear to do anything.  If you need to wait for that to finish before starting the next iteration, but the recursive call to `getSetImage()` inside that callback.

Comment: @jfriend00 I did try it with promise, async and await, but doing that it fired off API calls immediately.  I have to admit, I'm still not real sure about promise processing.
Also the con.query() does do the updates no prob, so not sure what you mean.  I don't show all possible error checking here, if that's what you mean?

Comment: It is definitely overflowing the stack also.  If I run the process in Node and debugging, that's what I get - with the final else and throw removed?! 
Actually I only tried async/await on the getSetImage() function - not everything.

Comment: Lots of other things wrong here.  None of your `throw ...` statements will do much useful as they just throw into asynchronous callbacks which you can't catch them from.

Comment: If I am following the code indentation properly, you are only calling `getSetImage()` recursively form within an asynchronous callback.  The stack will be empty at that point.  This code, as shown, will not cause a stack overflow from calling `getSetImage()` recursively.  Either this isn't your real code or there's something else going on causing a problem.  Please show the entire REAL code.

Comment: This code really wants to be rewritten with promises and `async/await`. There will be no recursion and it will be a LOT simpler.  If you're going to be programming in nodejs for any amount of time, it is completely worth it to learn how to use promises and `async/await`.  In this code, you can just switch to `request-promise` (though personally I prefer the `got()` library because the `request` family is in maintenance mode and no longer getting new features). And, then switch the promise interface for your database (which is built-in).

Comment: `await` will only  do anything useful if you are actually awaiting a promise so you HAVE to switch all asynchronous operation to be promises, not callbacks to use `async/await` with them.  And, error handling will be a lot simpler to do correctly with promises.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but every time I hit one of these situations, it's because something in my code that I thought was async really isn't async. Have you tried adding a processNextTick?

Comment: @jfriend00 I do get throw errors showing up?  I am trying to get up to speed and program properly with Node so appreciate any pointers and constructive criticisms.  :v)  If I need to scrap this and start over with promises (that's what it sounding like) then that's fine.  I'll do the research.  A quick outline of what you're suggesting would be good - not asking for you to code it form me tho. ;v)

Comment: @Brightstar - I saw that as a recommendation, but no, I haven't tried that.. I looked at using a trampoline function and a few other suggestions I could find - but it all seems like it's getting way more complicated then it should be.  I suspect the promise route is what I need.  Definitely want to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: @kgingeri It looks like the work of less than a minute to wrap something in a processNextTick and just see if it still blows up. If it doesn't then you've learned something. If you're processing purely synchronous calls then you should be approaching the problem a little differently. Good luck!

Comment: @Brightstar you are right - that is simple.  Not sure what I was reading previously but I think I will take jFriend00's advice and re-write promise based.  Gotta byte that bullet and understand it for sure.  I don't want to just copy and code blindly. I need to understand what's happening so I can trouble shoot properly when things go wrong!

Comment: @jfriend00 I've posted running code (without actual API strings and initial require() statements).  I am also running it in debug currently, to post any final errors.

Comment: Well, before you did that, I create an outline of the structure with `async/await`.  Hopefully you can learn from taht.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've said in all my comments, this would be a ton simpler using promises and `async/await`.  To do that, you need to switch all your asynchronous operations over to equivalents that use promises.

Here's a general outline based on the original pseudo-code you posted:

```
// use got() for promise version of request
const got = require('got');

// use require("mysql2/promise" for promise version of mysql

async function getSetImage(data) {

    for (let item of data) {
        if (item && item.id) {
            let url = uriHeader + uriPartA + item.id + uriPartB;
            let image = await got(url).json().catch(err => {
                // log and modify error, then rethrow
                console.log(err);
                err.msg = 'API Server is not responding\n';
                throw err;
            });
            if (image.value && image.value.length) {
                console.log('\nFound image for ' + item.id + '\n');
                let qry = 'update inventory set image = "' + image.value + '" where id = "' + item.id + '";';
                await con.query(qry).catch(err => {
                    console.log('ERROR:', err.message, '\nSQL:[' + err.sql + ']\n');
                    throw err;
                });
            }
        } else {
            // no image data found
            process.stdout.write('.'); //...show '.' for record, but no image
        }
    }
}

//...sql query is done, returning "result" - data rows
getSetImage(result).then(() => {
    console.log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Some notes about this code:

1. The `request()` library is no longer getting new features and is in maintenance mode and you need to change to a different library to get built-in promise support.  You could use `request-promise` (also in maintenance mode), but I recommend one of the newer libraries such as [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) that is more actively being developed.  It has some nice features (automatically checks status for you to be 2xx, built-in JSON parsing, etc...) which I've used above to save code.
2. `mysql2/promise` has built-in promise support which you get with `const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');`.  I'd recommend you switch to it.
3. Because of the user of `async/await` here, you can just loop through your data in a regular `for` loop.  And, no recursion required.  And, no stack build-up.
4. The way promises work by default, any rejected promises will automatically terminate the flow here.  The only reason I'm using `.catch()` in a couple places is just for custom logging and tweaking of the error object.  I then rethrow which propagates the error back to the caller for you.
5. You can tweak the error handling to your desire.  The usual convention with promises is to throw an Error object (not a string) and that's often what callers are expecting to see if the promise rejects.
6. This code can be easily customized to log errors and continue on to subsequent items in the array.  Your original code did not appear to do that so I wrote it to abort if it got an error.

Comment: This is very helpful.  I will digest it line by line!  Thanks @jfriend00!

Comment: one last question (off topic): How do you keep up with current libraries and find the best ones etc? Can you recommend sources? ie. I know I can check https://www.npmjs.com/ but there's tons of packages!  Thanks again.

Comment: @kgingeri - I don't know any way other than researching an individual topic to see what people are talking about and recommending and hanging out here to discover what people are using.  I only discovered that `request()` and `request-promise()` were in maintenance mode by reading here and that post pointed me to a list of alternatives from which I liked the way `got()` worked.

Comment: @kgingeri - If you're just searching npmjs and finding things, I look for libraries that are being actively worked on and are used by a lot of people as there is a lot of dead code you can find and using one of those ends up meaning you're on the hook for maintaining it yourself.  That still may be better than writing your own code from scratch, but it's even better if someone else is maintaining it for you.  I also look at the open bug reports and see what kinds of bugs there are and how much attention is being paid to them.